# Particular - ServiceControl is always Stopped

Tags: nsb-servicecontrol

I installed Service Control(V1.20.0) recently to my QA server, I install it using ServiceControl Management Utility , I didn’t change the default values, I didn’t move DB location. 
I was able to browse to the RavenDB when I am in maintenance mode. 
The particular endpoints are created, I also have non-expired license.

This is what i found in the db log file

> Microsoft.Isam.Esent.Interop.EsentInvalidInstanceException: Invalid
>   instance handle    at Microsoft.Isam.Esent.Interop.Api.Check(Int32
>   err) in
>   C:\Work\ravendb\SharedLibs\Sources\managedesent-61618\EsentInterop\Api.cs:line
>   2739    at
>   Microsoft.Isam.Esent.Interop.Api.JetBeginSession(JET_INSTANCE
>   instance, JET_SESID& sesid, String username, String password) in
>   C:\Work\ravendb\SharedLibs\Sources\managedesent-61618\EsentInterop\Api.cs:line
>   823    at
>   Raven.Storage.Esent.StorageActions.DocumentStorageActions..ctor(JET_INSTANCE
>   instance, String database, TableColumnsCache tableColumnsCache,
>   OrderedPartCollection`1 documentCodecs, IUuidGenerator uuidGenerator,
>   IDocumentCacher cacher, EsentTransactionContext transactionContext,
>   TransactionalStorage transactionalStorage) in
>   c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-2.5\Raven.Database\Storage\Esent\StorageActions\General.cs:line
>   76

Answer (score 0):

With the amazing help of Particular team, I was able to solve the issue. In my case the problem was I have created the Particular.ServiceControl queue manually. And it needs to be transnational, this was the error i was getting in event viewer:

> Queue must be transactional if you configure your endpoint to be
>   transactional

Deleting the queue, and let Service Control Management tool take care of creating all necessary queues.